# The sum of the cube of the first n odd numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, solution-verification, induction

Prove that The sum of the cube of the first n odd numbers = $n^2(2n^2-1)$ 
That is 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1)^3 = n^2(2n^2-1)$$

First I tried to solve it by induction: 
$Basis-step:$

For  $n=1$ we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1)^3 = 1$$
and $$n^2(2n^2-1) = 1$$

$Induction-step:$
Let $n  \in \mathbb{N},$ $$Assume  \sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1)^3 = n^2(2n^2-1)$$ $$Prove \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} (2i-1)^3 = (n+1)^2(2(n+1)^2-1)$$

I know that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} (2i-1)^3 =  \sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1)^3 + (2(n+1)-1)^3 $$  But i was not able to reach a solution.
If anyone can give a small hint, that would be helpful.

Comment: Hint $\sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1)^3 =8 \sum i^3 -12    \sum i^2 + 6  \sum i - n$ and use the well-known compact formulas for the 3 sums.

Comment: +1 : to your question for good work shown.

Comment: So, this proves in particular that even perfect numbers other than $6$ are the sum of consecutive odd cubes beginning with $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that's missing is to prove that$$\bigl(2(n+1)-1\bigr)^3+n^2(2n^2-1)=(n+1)^2\bigl(2(n+1)^2-1\bigr).$$But if you expand both sides of this equality, you will get $2 n^4+8 n^3+11 n^2+6 n+1$ in each case.